# Is it possible to create an equivalent environment of a KVM guest using QEMU for Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have a KVM guest in a datacenter that is my production server for a service I am developing. I would like to create an equivalent virtual environment on my Windows machine so I can be sure that operations I do in the VM on my machine - such as compiling custom Linux kernels for the guest - can be transferred identically to the production server.

Is it possible to configure QEMU for Windows in such a way that it creates a VM precisely equivalent to the KVM guest environment? Or are there other subtleties in the way that KVM handles virtual machines that would make this infeasible?

Comment: Does your production VM really need a custom kernel?! Most Linux distributions already include all of the kernel drivers you would need for running in a KVM virtual machine, as well as those for 99% or more of applications you might want to run.

Comment: Yes, it's a grsecurity-patched kernel. Just need to make sure it'll run the same in the production VM as my development VM on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

No. QEMU is a software processor emulator. KVM is a kernel module which provides access to hardware virtualization extensions.

When run on a Linux virt host, the two combine to provide accelerated virtualization "hardware" for guest OSes to run on.

I wouldn't really consider this a "subtlety", it's pretty much what defines KVM virtualization.